# How to create rigid panel of exact size (or something similar?)

Tags: java, jpanel

I have a array of line of components and I would like to show a integer value in each line, within a rigid area.

```
for (int i=0; i < CounterNumber; i++){
    CounterPanel[i].setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    CounterPanel[i].add(Counters[i].GetFront());
    CounterPanel[i].add(Counters[i]);
    CounterPanel[i].add(Counters[i].GetBack());
    contents.add(CounterPanel[i]);
}
```

Counters[i] acts as the constructor of some graphical elements. My integer is part of the Front part.

```
   NextActP.add(NextAct); //My panel and the Label
   NextActP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
   front.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
   front.add(delete);
   front.add(name);
   front.add(NextActP);
```

Which I return to the UI with the public method (.getFront). NextAct is a JLabel which's value I change with the .setText method. Assuming it's "0" at start, all is okay, but when the integer rises to 2 digits, the panel expands and pushes my other components more right, and with the initial size of the window, makes them disappear. I could format it at start with "00", though the elements still move around as the value changes.

I tried both

```
NextActP.setSize(20, 15);
NextActP.setBounds(0, 0, 20, 15);
```

for the panel, though it doesn't seem to have effect. How can I make it rigid area that does not move other things around?

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variable are correct and other are not. Be consistent!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what "rigid" area means, but you can try to use AbsoluteLayout, I don't know if it can fit your goal.

Comment: I upped a small image. http://i.imgur.com/p7marOn.jpg

There is the "next action" box, with values 7 and 10. As you can see, the value 10 expands the little box. I would like it to be of same size regardless whether there is 7 or 10.

Comment: @AzureDrake strange thing , it never happened to me, but maybe because I never use FlowLayout before. Did you try changing your Layout?